Trying to make a smoothly rotating and moving camera
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;

    public float smoothingspeed_movement = 0.125f;
    public float smoothingspeed_rotation= 0.5f;
    public Vector3 offset;

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothingspeed_movement);
        transform.position = smoothedPosition;
        
        Vector3 desiredRotation = target.eulerAngles + offset;
        Vector3 smoothedRotation = Vector3.Lerp(transform.rotation.eulerAngles, desiredRotation, smoothingspeed_rotation);
        
        transform.eulerAngles = smoothedRotation;
    }
}

The problem I am facing is that when the camera moved to the left, from rotation 0, back to 359, it smooths the movement towards the right, instead of smoothing to the left. So it always does a 360-rotation.

Do note: you should probably be using Update, rather than FixedUpdate to do interpolation. FixedUpdate always runs at a set framerate (60fps, by default), while Update runs every frame. For players with monitors that can display > 60 fps, there will be slight stutters, since the movement will be unnecessarily limited to 60 fps.

Don't use FixedUpdate but rather Update and use Time.deltaTime to erase any frame rate dependencies

Instead of interpolating the euler angles, you can spherically interpolate (slerp) on two quaternions: the old rotation, and the new rotation:
Quaternion desiredRotation = target.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(offset);
Quaternion smoothedRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, desiredRotation, smoothingspeed_rotation);

transform.rotation = smoothedRotation;


thank you, was trying to figure that out but i couldn't make Quaternion code work by myself.
